# Building Angular 2 application with component oriented architecture

Tags: angular, components

Angular 2 is component based, any article that explains building an application in Component Oriented Architecture.

Comment: Please refer this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about what questions (not) to ask and how to ask good questions.